# Honeywell thermostat issue

Tags: thermostat

I have a Honeywell thermostat with M-F schedule like so...

- 6:30 am (wake) - 70
- 6:45 am (leave) - 63
- 4:00 pm (return) - 70
- 9:00 pm (sleep) - 63

The Honeywell actually displays wake, leave, return, sleep when setting it. Now at 5am this morning, the target temperature was 70 degrees and it was heating the house!

1. Is this normal, is it trying to take 1 hour and 30 minutes to get to 70 degrees?  (This seems wrong...I don't want it to start heating until the wake time is hit TBH).
2. If that is wrong, is there a factory reset (as clearly this thing is way SCREWED up)?

Comment: What sort of HVAC system do you have?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Obviously, something's wrong with the thermostat or its programming. I'll guess the latter, but there's no way we can be more helpful from here without a lot more info.

Comment: Keep in mind it takes time to change the temperature of the entire house. Do you want it to be 70 *at* 6:30, or *start to heat to 70* at 6:30? If the latter, how big is the house? Is the 15 minutes you want it at 70 even enough time to increase the temperature of the entire house by 7 degrees?

Comment: Many thermostats have a ‘holiday’ mode. Perhaps you have entered it.

Comment: The stat may have some features and be trying to get the home to 70 by the set time. As far as how long it takes to reach temp depends on the home size the furnace size in BTU's the insulation and Delta from the starting temp to desired temp. On many thermostats if you pull the battery backup and turn of the power it will reset the memory.

Comment: What is the model # of the thermostat?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal, is it trying to take 1 hour and 30 minutes to get to 70 degrees?

It depends. Let's back up and talk about what Honeywell likes to call "In Recovery".

When you set your thermostat up, the thermostat has to learn how fast your HVAC can change the temp. It does this during a natural cycle so you're not running your heater in Summer or vice versa. Once it knows about how long the process will take, it will then kick the HVAC in so that **it reaches your desired temp at the time you set it for**. In other words, when you set it to 70 by 6:30am, it's going to kick your heater in earlier to reach that temp by 6:30, not to start trying to change it at 6:30.

Now, 90 minutes for a 7 degree change sounds nuts but if it's stuck in learning mode it might be confused as to how long it takes. You might want to consult your manual (or call Honeywell) and see if there's something not correct there.

Comment: Is anyone aware of a thermostat brand that doesn't try to do any prediction/learning?